# A question about the 'polarity sensitive' any

Tags: negative-polarity-items

In academic literature, the '**free-choice**' **any** and the '**polarity sensitive**' **any** are often discussed, when in fact the latter is the '**negative polarity**' **any**.

In the majority of the cases, authors call the any '**polarity sensitive**' **any**. Is it more accurate to call it that because there is some exceptions within the category of '**negative polarity**' **any**s? Or, is it because historically people have been accustomed to using it?

Comment: _Polarity_ is a metaphor, based on magnetism, to refer to the relation between a linguistic operator (normally negation, quantification, or modality) and its focus item in an utterance. They are linked, in other words, like an NPI and the negative licensing it, or a quantifier and the NP it determines. Saying that a lexical item is _polarity-sensitive_ simply doesn't specify the operator. However, since _any_ is an NPI, it's negative-polarity-sensitive. It's not more accurate either way; it's just another way of referring. Plus NPI _any_ is much more frequent than free-choice _any_.

Comment: Thanks, John. So in a nutshell it's been used assuming everyone feels at the same time that authors are pointing to negative polarity because the tendency is well known.

Answer (score 2):

"Negative polarity" items aren't only used in negative sentences, but also in interrogative sentences, for example ("Do you have any money?"). Perhaps this is the reason some authors prefer the term "polarity sensitive".

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> *Polarity* is a metaphor, based on magnetism, to refer to the relation between a linguistic operator (normally negation, quantification, or modality) and its focus item in an utterance. They are linked, in other words, like an NPI and the negative licensing it, or a quantifier and the NP it determines. Saying that a lexical item is *polarity-sensitive* simply doesn't specify the operator. However, since *any* is an NPI, it's negative-polarity-sensitive. It's not more accurate either way; it's just another way of referring. Plus NPI *any* is much more frequent than free-choice *any*.

Comment: I can't make any sense of that.