# Why can't "any" be used as subject in negative sentences, while "no" can?

Tags: negation, subjects, determiners

Why is it that *any* cannot be used as subject in negative sentences, while *no* can?

An example pair of sentences might be:

> No children came.
>
> Any children didn't come.

---

Please note that the following questions, which have been linked to this one as a basis for closing it, are spectacular in their inaptness:

> [A question about the 'polarity sensitive' any](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/425141/a-question-about-the-polarity-sensitive-any)
>
> [Use of “ever” in non-negated sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68247/use-of-ever-in-non-negated-sentence)

Comment: "Don't any keys fit the lock?"

Comment: @Greybeard Polar questions are not negative or positive sentences in any meaningful way. Polar questions essentially have no polarity. Notice that the answer to a polar question is the same regardless of whether it is the "negative" or "positive" version. Polar questions are weird beasts!

Comment: What an interesting question! I think this has to do with the idea of negative "scope". I think @John Lawler might come to your rescue here!

Comment: any children is not a subject. "Any who came were late".

Comment: @Lambie Que? "Any children are welcome". "Any children who came were late" etc, etc.

Comment: OK. But remember, you asked.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. How can polar questions not have any polarity?

Comment: @HotLicks Notice the "in any meaningful way". If I ask "Is hotlicks not older than my t-shirt?" and "Is hotlicks older than my t-shirt?" it doesn't matter which question you ask, the answer is always the same - and in English you can just say "yes" or "no" to either. Both involve a choice between the positive and negative propositions.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. **I was referring to the OP's sentence**: Any children didn't come. In any case, any and no with children don't make a subject. The subject is the word children.

Comment: @Lambie Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: In this "sentence": Any children didn't come. the words "any children" are not a subject. In the sentence: No children came. children is the subject and no is a determiner.

Comment: Going to get anticipatory popcorn.

Comment: "Any" may be used in an emphatic negative way. Question about an event: "*Female children were not welcome?*." Answer: "*ANY children were unwelcome!*"

Comment: @Anton That's the Free Choice _any_. BTW, I forgot to mention Zeno Vendler's wonderful 1967 article "Each and Every, Any and All" in _Linguistics in Philosophy_.

Comment: @JohnLawler perhaps just as well.  Zeno is elusive (like the hare in the eponymous paradox?). On quick online search, at best I only find an abstract of the article.

Answer (score 17):

First, the question is out of left field. The ungrammaticality of

- **Any children didn't come*

doesn't have a thing to do with subjects.  It has to do with how one uses the word *any*,
which is rather a complex subject.

There are at least two English words *any*:

1. Free-Choice *any*, as in *Pick a number -- **any** number,* or ***Anybody** can do that.*
   Free-choice *any* **can** be a subject, but it usually occurs with a modal like *can* or *able*.
   It's a special term with a special grammar and meaning, basically "Choose one".
2. Negative Polarity *any*. This is by far the most common use of *any*, and it (and all its compounds like *anybody, anyone, anywhere,* etc.) is a [Negative Polarity Item](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/63728/15299). That means it can only be used grammatically inside the scope of a semantic [negative trigger](http://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/NPIs.pdf). These include [negatives](http://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf), questions, and a lot of idiomatic constructions.

Negative polarity items are determined by removing negative triggers and seeing whether the NPI is still grammatical. E.g, the boldface NPIs below:

- *I have**n't** **ever** been there.* ~ **I have/I've **ever** been there*
- *She has**n't** been here **in weeks*** ~ **She has/She's been here **in weeks***
- *He does**n't** have **any** assistants.* ~ **He has **any** assistants*
- *This should**n't** **take long***. ~ **This should **take long***

Questions are negative environments, as it happens, so NPIs can occur there,

- *Have you **ever** been there?*
- *Does he have **any** assistants?*
- *Will this **take long**?*

even as subjects.

- *Is **anybody** else coming?*

So, since NPIs have to occur with negatives, the reason why **Any children didn't come* is ungrammatical is because *any* isn't in the scope of a negative trigger. *Not any children* would be clunky but grammatical, though *No children* is better. There's also upstairs negation, as in

- *It's **not** true that **any** children came.*
- *I do**n't** think that **any** children came.*
- *He did**n't** claim that **any** children came.*

where the negative in the main clause licenses the *any* in the complement clause.

tl;dr -- If a sentence sounds odd, see if there's a negative in it, or whether adding negation makes it better.

Comment: Popcorn optional

Comment: *Any* is not within the scope of negative *didn't* because it occurs outside of the negative verb phrase, right  - i.e. higher up? [[Any children] [**didn't come**]].

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'd say. Typically the negative precedes the NPI, but scope is not a matter of position.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer, is there an easy way of figuring out the "stairness" of the two verb phrases? Is it the "that" before the complement clauses in your examples?

Comment: @MatějVais "upstairs/downstairs" is a mathematical concept indicating that, in a complex fraction, a number to a negative power  should be moved from the denominator line to the numerator line, and vice versa. (See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9TvZe6V1hg). I thus assume that John Lawler is saying that in a two clause statement, and for the purpose of being idiomatic, the negative moves from the main to the subordinate clause and vice versa.

Comment: @JohnLawler. I note that "that any children came" is not a sentence - it is a noun clause - and that the OP asks *"Why can't "any" be used as subject in negative **sentences**, while "no" can?"*

Comment: "Upstairs/downstairs" is a metaphorical term in (some forms of) syntax. It refers to tree structures, which put the main clause at the top and then all the dependent clauses depending down from them. Each subordinate clause uses a different "staircase", and many rules apply cyclically in each ascending clause, starting from the bottom. That's known as the _Syntactic Cycle_ -- the same vertical metaphoric dimension referred to in the cyclic rule known as _Subject Raising_ -- the downstairs subject becomes an argument in the upstairs clause. OK?

Comment: The meaning of the metaphor is obvious if you're familiar with tree diagrams, but not otherwise. Sorry to mislead anyone. As for the original question, as stated, the simple answer is that _no_ is indeed negative and makes it a "negative sentence", but _any_ is **not** a negative like _no_, and therefore **doesn't** make it a "negative sentence." That's why we rarely pay attention to Original Questions, since they often depend on false assumptions, like the idea that sentences are intrinsically "negative", instead of identifying the source of the negation.

Comment: I like how this answer really shows that English, in not using negative concordance like "He didn't have none", is in fact much more complicated and confusing because of it.

Comment: As I keep saying, Negation is **complicated**. It's an Operator, like Quantification and Modality, and they all have very very complex and arbitrary powers, like binding variables and interlocking scopes. To say nothing of idioms -- NPIs are **all** idioms.

Comment: You could of course say **Every child didn't come.**  It's a bit awkward, but grammatically valid.

Comment: It's also ambiguous, because it could mean they all stayed away, or that only some came, not all.